# In a numpy record array how to access certain element value in python

Tags: python, numpy, record

I have the following numpy record array. How can I access the offset of a specific element in the array? In other words for this example I want to print the offset of just the array[1] element.

Pseudo Example

```
print(array[1,offset])

#I want the output to be 
02
```

Actual code

```
dtype={
    'names' : ('name','offset','bit_span'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20')}

instance= np.zeros(3,dtype)

array[0]=('register','00','0')
array[1]=('register_1','02','0')
array[2]=('register_2','04','0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the records by name, e.g.

```
dtype={
    'names' : ('name','offset','bit_span'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20','U20')}

instance= np.zeros(3,dtype)

instance[0]=('register','00','0')
instance[1]=('register_1','02','0')
instance[2]=('register_2','04','0')

instance[1]['offset']
# '02'
```